# How do I return the most commonly occurring *text* value in a column, filtered by a different column?

Tags: filter, google-sheets-formula, index-match

I have two sheets. Rows are unique in both sheets.

Sheet1, column A = exhaustive list of domains (e.g. 'madeupdomain1.com')
Sheet2, column B = exhaustive list of URLs (e.g. 'madeupdomain1.com/article1', 'madeupdomain1.com/article2', 'madeupdomain1.com/article3', ...)
Sheet2, column C = lists an author (e.g. 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', ...). Authors appear multiple times.

How do I return the most frequent author for a given domain?

I.e. how do I find the most common *text* value, filtered by some other value?

Sheet2:

| Domain | URL | Author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| madeupdomain1.com | madeupdomain1.com/article1 | Alice |
| madeupdomain1.com | madeupdomain1.com/article2 | Bob |
| madeupdomain1.com | madeupdomain1.com/article3 | Charlie |
| madeupdomain2.com | madeupdomain2.com/article1 | Alice |
| madeupdomain2.com | madeupdomain2.com/article2 | Bob |
| madeupdomain2.com | madeupdomain2.com/article3 | Alice |
| madeupdomain3.com | madeupdomain3.com/article1 | Alice |
| madeupdomain3.com | madeupdomain3.com/article2 | Charlie |
| madeupdomain3.com | madeupdomain3.com/article3 | Bob |

I have tried:

```
=INDEX(MODE.MULT(IFNA(MATCH(FILTER(Sheet2!$C$2:$C, Sheet2!$B$2:$B=Sheet1!$A2),UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!$C$2:$C, Sheet2!$B$2:$B=Sheet1!A2)),0))))
```

So I was expecting for 'madeupdomain2.com' to see 'Alice' returned, but I just get a numerical value (which I guess is caused by using MODE?). Urgh.

Any help much appreciated!